# ANDROID_HOME environment variable issues with Appium

Tags: android, macos, appium

I am trying to run Appium on the command line with OSX El Capitan to test an Android application. I have been able to use Appium many times with the GUI version but have not had the same luck in the terminal. The issues I am facing stem from setting the `$ANDROID_HOME` environment variable. I have read other posts regarding this problem but the solutions have not helped me.

I have the following in my `bash_profile` :

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/adamjakiela/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

I then run `source ~/.bash_profile` and am able to start the SDK by running the `android` command. I can also print the environment variable:

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME       
/Users/adamjakiela/Library/Android/sdk
```

But then, when I run Appium on the command line I receive the following message which eventually leads to other problems:

```
warn: The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set to the Android SDK root directory path.
```

I can also run the Appium doctor and see the following:

```
Running Android Checks
✖ ANDROID_HOME is not set
Appium-Doctor detected problems. Please fix and rerun Appium-Doctor.
```

Additionally, I have installed all the build tools for the applicable versions of Android and have had no problem build my applications or using the Appium GUI version by pointing it to the $ANDROID_HOME location.

Why are the errors shown by Appium inconsistant with the fact that the $ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and that other applications are able to use the Android SDK?

Comment: Do ADB commands work?

Comment: Yes, as long as I run source ~/.bash_profile beforehand.

Comment: hm that could be part of the problem. editing your bash_profile file should be a global/permanent change so you don't have to keep using that source command.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. I also tried editing the root bash_profile but the problem persisted.

Comment: what do you get when you echo $PATH?

Comment: /Users/adamjakiela/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin which obviously does not include android. I will look into this.

Comment: good catch @econoMichael. Looks like your bash_profile isn't being used. r u using any custom bash, like zsh for example?